# Paperback anthology, likely named something like "Happy Death-Day to You"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

This one is particularly frustrating because I think I remember the exact title of the book as being *Happy Death-Day to You*, except searches for that title don't bring up anything useful. The cover had a figure (a clown?) holding a bunch of balloons with skulls on them. The collection included a story with the same title as the book, which was about a boy obsessed with death. He either finds, or someone sends him, a card that has "Happy Death-Day to You" written on it with directions to a building (a restaurant?), which thrills him. When he arrives there, he learns that there is a party for him. When he enters, he learns that it is indeed to celebrate his death, and he's killed (I want to say that the guests he saw were distinctly supernatural). The second story involved a child, whose mother is dead, finding that they can make phone calls from her grave (I don't remember if they bring the phone or if it's already there, or whether the phone is explicitly plugged into the ground. I do remember that it was a landline phone, I think black rotary dial). Their father shows up, angry at them, and they offer the phone, saying it's for him. After their father answers, something happens (I don't remember if the father was pushed, or just fell) and the father strikes his head on the mother's tombstone, killing him. Then, the child resumes the call.

The latter story is not "Long Distance Call" by Richard Matheson.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it. Apparently the hyphen was confusing things. *[Happy Deathday to You: And Other Stories to Give You Nightmares](http://booklikes.com/happy-deathday-to-you-and-other-stories-to-give-you-nightmares-george-e-sta/book,2912017)* by [George Edward Stanley](http://www.equitainment.com.au/factsheet.asp?ID=17), and is apparently now quite rare given the cheapest I've seen it is $80.

> A collection of chilling stories pits teens Mandy, Billy, Francine, and Dorothy against their own personal demons, including the undead, fellow classmates, a dead older sister, and a twisted little brother.

[image: Happy Deathday to You]

Comment: If you're not a stickler for condition, abe.com currently has a "good" copy listed for $4.57 with free shipping in the US.

Comment: @user14111: Truthfully, after having bought online a few books I read as a child, I'm starting to realize the nostalgia filter is superior to the real thing.